# fancybox in ie9 displaying left bottom

Tags: fancybox-2

Works fine in firefox but displaying bottom left in ie9

I assume it's either something to do with css in ie9 or the DOCTYPE?

Any help appreciated. The site this is happening on is below.

http://bydezign.co.nz/Products/Chairs/ManoliChair.aspx

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135066/157574

Answer (score 0):

Where to begin

Okay lets start with validation

http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fbydezign.co.nz%2FProducts%2FChairs%2FManoliChair.aspx

Now a lot of those errors are I think as a result of not adhering to your transistional doctype. I always go xhtml1 BUT you may have your reasons for the transistional (though I can't believe anyone worth their salt nowadays would not use xhtml as it is pretty much the standard.

Sorting your doctype MAY (and probably will) solve your rendering issues but if it doesn't I would look at your use of tables for layout. This is a very big 'no-no'. You should be using divs and css for layout. It will give you much better design capabilities. Tables are not semantically correct to use for layout - they are for displaying tabular data.

Fix these first and see if that solves your issue (99% confident just the doctype and getting it through validation will resolve the issue